# How to build a rank in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with the database.

I have a table of the following structure:

```
name    type   data  frequen
name1   type1   d1      10
name2   type1   d2      15
name2   type1   d3      25
name2   type2   d4      02
name3   type2   d5      05
name3   type3   d6      20
```

I need to create a rank of the most frequent features of each name and each type by sorting the frequency in descending order.

Example:

```
name    type   data  frequen  rank

name1   type1   d1      10     1
name2   type1   d2      15     2
name2   type1   d3      25     3
name2   type2   d4      02     1
name3   type2   d5      05     2
name3   type3   d6      20     1
```

Would anyone know how to do something like this? I am using mysql with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: for the combination *name2* and *type1* you start numbering with 2?

Comment: Yes, because they are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this in MySQL is using variables:

```
  select t.*,
         (@rn := if(@t = type, @rn + 1,
                    if(@t := type, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as rank
  from t cross join
       (select @t := '', @rn := 0) params
  order by name, freq;
```